# Spring MVC won't display correct database value after update

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my controller, put a value from a `MySQL` database into a `ModelAndView object`

There is a separate program that updates the table and the **MVC** is supposed to grab that value so there are no forms to update that table.

When the **table is updated**, and when I **hit refresh on the browser**, the values will not update on the page.

**Controller**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Secured({ "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN" })
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView defaultPage(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder
            .getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("/hello");
    // Redirects to admin page if user has admin role
    if (authorities.toString().contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin");
    }
    /////
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String userName = auth.getName();
    User userInfo = userDAO.getUserInfo(userName);
    System.out.println("Here's the thing " + userInfo.getLastname() + " " + userInfo.getUserDetails());
    Details details = userDAO.getDetailsInfo(userInfo.getUserDetails().getLastname(),
            userInfo.getUserDetails().getPostcode());
    Plugs plugs = userDAO.getPlugInfo(details.getMacAddress()); 
    String json = plugs.getJson();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json); //this is the value that is not updating
    String name = obj.getJSONObject("meta").getJSONObject("locate").getString("value");
    System.out.println(name); 
    view.addObject("json", obj);
    return view;
}
```

I know this is pretty looked down upon, but I putting that value in **Javascript.**

like this:

```
<c:set var="json" value="${json}"/> 

var __data__ = ${json};
```

Why won't the MVC display the correct value when the database is updated?

*I want it to update on refresh*

> EDIT: I've disabled caching and cleared cache still have a problem. Any help?

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure what you mean by jsp reloaded

Comment: Is there any application level cache or second level cache sitting in your app infront of the database?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I'm not entirely sure

Comment: if there is any cache in your app, that could be the reason why you are not seeing the updated value. You may want to check that.

Comment: I'm not sure if cache is the problem. I mean it could be, but I cleared cache and set headers and it still doesn't show the correct value.

Comment: if you debug here: Plugs plugs = userDAO.getPlugInfo(details.getMacAddress());  the value is updated?

Comment: @mvlaicevich I fixed my problem, but thanks for commenting anyways

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Definitely `PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED` scope is the root cause for your problem as you identified. The reason below:

With `PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION` scope, Spring framework takes responsibility of managing the life cycle of the injected the `entitymanager`. The life of `TRANSACTION` scope is tied to the underlying `transaction` and upon commit/rollback of the transaction the `entityManager` is closed by the spring framework.

But with `PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED` scope, Spring framework takes responsibility of only injecting the `entitymanager`. The life cycle of `EXTENDED` scoped entity manager is not tied to the user `transaction` and it can span multiple transactions. It is up to the application/user to explicitly close the `entityManager` once we are done with it. If not it will remain open forever (or till Spring container is closed).

I presume in your `userDAO` you are not closing `entityManager` explicitly. And also 'userDAO' could be a singleton. So the same `entityManager` that got injected only once is being used across multiple calls (or http requests)

With this the `entityManager' remains open forever and so when you try to access any object (User/Plugin/UserDetails) the`entityManager` checks its first level cache, it will check its first level cache which it finds in it (that got loaded for the first time) and returns this object form its first level cache (which is stale) instead of hitting the database for the data.

And obviously with `TRANSACTION` scope the `entityManager` is closed by the Spring framework whenever transaction is completed (or method exits). This results in creating an `entityManager` for each request (in your case web request) hits the the database which has the updated data.

See if this link helps. http://forum.spring.io/forum/other-spring-related/ejb/18445-injection-of-persistencecontext-with-persistencecontexttype-extended

Comment: Oh this is great stuff. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

So the solution I have has nothing to do with the code I posted, but in my UserDAO.java class.

Simple change.

From this:

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager em;
```

To this:

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
private EntityManager em;
```

and it works. Thank for the people who commented and tried to help/

EDIT: I hate answering my own questions, so if someone could have an in depth explanation on why this works, I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjio.html

Disable the JPA second level cache otherwise the entity manager does not recognise changed data which was changed directly in the database
Put

```
@Cacheable(false)
```

onto your entity

Comment: I already said what the solution and I also said disabling any cache didn't work.