# Transaction management in JSP with Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, transactions, hibernate-session

Is there a way to simply obtain detached entities in a Springboot application?

**In order to illustrate** (I leave the strict minimum) :

Here a repository of entity A:

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> { (...) }
```

Here a manager of object from A class (does some atomicals operations):

```
public class AManager {

    private ARepository aRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public A getA(long id) {
        return aRepository.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

Here a service of object from A class (does more complexes operations):

```
public class AService {

    private AManager aManager;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public A getA(long id) {
        return aManager.getA(id);
    }

}
```

And here a jsp which calls my service:

```
(...)
A a = aService.getA(1);
a.someproperty = value; // Do not automatically commit this modification!!!!
(...)
```

For safety, I prefer that the entities I get out of the service are detached (in fact not more managed). But I have lots of entities and often collections of them.

The only solution I found for the moment is:

```
public A getA(long id) {
    A a= aRepository.findOne(id);
    Hibernate.initialize(a.collectionProperty);
    entityManager.detach(a);
    
    return a;
}
```

Did I have this only solution? What to do when I have a Collection of entities? Is there any configuration to manage that in Springboot? in Hibernate?

Comment: You have `@Transactional` on the service class method. So once you come out of the service method, the transaction will end and the entities would automatically be detached unless you have a `@Transaction` configured or Transaction is started at some other place even before service class and so that is spawning the entire HTTP request. Are you really seeing the modification that is made in jsp of `entity A` getting committed to the DB once you come out of the service class method.

Comment: Yes I see the modification in the database. I allready think about a Transaction wraping the request, but I found nothing. I did not do any configuration meaning something like this.

Comment: Are you using any framework for web (jsp)? I mean struts, Spring MVC etc..Or it just a jsp that accesses the manager directly? Just guessing, can you add `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` in spring boot conf file and try, because it is enabled by default.

Comment: `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true` will enables `OpenSessionInViewFilter` which opens the `session`, binds it to the `transaction` when request started and and closes it after the request processing done. So I think if you set `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` in spring boot conf file `application.properties` or yaml file, that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a spring boot application, [Spring Boot by default registers OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jpa-in-web-environment). This will open the `session` (or entityManager), binds it to the `transaction` when request starts and and closes it after the request processing is done.

So any changes you are make till the request is not completed are getting tracked, thus are the JSP modifications to the entities, and committed to the DB.

So I think if you set `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` in spring boot conf file `application.properties` or yaml file, that should help.

Comment: Thanks! I waste 3 days thinking I loose my mind and know anything more about the transactions!

Comment: Apart from [Spring doc for transaction management](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html), few links that talks about [transaction internals](http://www.codingpedia.org/jhadesdev/how-does-spring-transactional-really-work/) and [persitence context extended vs transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353840/spring-mvc-wont-display-correct-database-value-after-update) gives some insight and might help.